# Secure Password Generation With Random Chars

Tags: ruby, security, password-generator

I am trying to generate a random password that contains special chars using ruby. I would like to know if there is a standard for generating such passwords. I have considered using a weighted probability distribution and assigning weights such that there is a higher probability of picking special chars from , but I am not sure if this is a widely-accepted standard.

Comment: What has your research told you? Currently your question is asking us to recommend solutions or pages. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use SecureRandom ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html)):

```
require 'securerandom'

password = SecureRandom.base64(15)
# => "vkVuWvPUWSMcZf9nn/dO"
```

Comment: This will generate strings with a special character only 46.875% of the time. There is a 2/64 chance that the character will be a `+` or a `/`, which multiplied by 15 is 0.46875.

Answer (score 16):

Ruby comes with just such a module `SecureRandom`. You can generate random strings:

```
require "securerandom"

SecureRandom.hex 1 # => "e1"
SecureRandom.hex 2 # => "dcdd"
SecureRandom.hex 3 # => "93edc6"
SecureRandom.hex 5 # => "01bf5657ce"
SecureRandom.hex 8 # => "3cc72f70146ea286"

SecureRandom.base64 2  # => "d5M="
SecureRandom.base64 3  # => "EJ1K"
SecureRandom.base64 5  # => "pEeGO68="
SecureRandom.base64 8  # => "muRa+tO0RqU="
SecureRandom.base64 13 # => "1f8y7xsvaCEw0hwkjg=="
```

There is now a cryptographically secure version of the above called [SysRandom](https://github.com/cryptosphere/sysrandom) which some people [are recommending](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12440807).

With the gem `simple-password-gen` You can also generate [random and pronounceable passwords](https://github.com/dmke/simple-password-gen):

```
require "simple-password-gen"

Password.random 8 # => "#TFJ)Vtz3"
Password.pronounceable 13 # => "vingastusystaqu"
```

Finally, and just for fun (I recommend SysRandom), I wrote a small gem a while back to [generate random strings based on template strings](https://github.com/DiegoSalazar/monkey_string#random-string-generator). Although it doesn't include special chars, it would be a trivial addition. Feel free to submit an issue for it if it interests you.

Answer (score 4):

The ruby's built-in [SecureRandom](https://github.com/ruby/securerandom) module has convenient methods since ruby 2.5.

```rb
require "securerandom"

# If you need A-Za-z0-9
SecureRandom.alphanumeric(10)

# If you want to specify characters (excluding similar characters)
# However, this method is NOT PUBLIC and it might be changed someday.
SecureRandom.send(:choose, [*'A'..'Z', *'a'..'z', *'0'..'9'] - ['I', 'l', '1', 'O', '0'], 10)

# Old ruby compatible version
chars = [*'A'..'Z', *'a'..'z', *'0'..'9']
10.times.map { chars[SecureRandom.random_number(chars.length)] }.join
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is by using the string_pattern gem https://github.com/MarioRuiz/string_pattern

This will generate 1000 unique strings from 6 to 20 characters including letters, and force to include special characters and numbers

```
require 'string_pattern'
1000.times {
    puts :"6-20:L/$N/&".gen 
}
```